# Search multiple CSV files for specific row and save specific columns along with date information

Tags: python, csv

I have a directory full of CSV file which contains information about the resources used by virtual machines. These files are named 'VM Resources - 2018-06-01 070001.csv' etc and contain ~400 lines.

I'm currently only interested in extracting the entry for one server (Let's call it MAILSERVER01) and the columns `VMName` (index 0), `Total Storage (GB)` (index 8) and the date from the file name.

I can use something like:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = "my_dir_full_path"
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.csv"))
```

But this doesn't give me the date field that I need. I'm hoping to eventually be able to plug this information into a time series to predict when a server (all 400) is likely to require a disk extension but in the interim need to create the time series data.

I am trying to get an output CSV looking like:

```
VMName,Total Storage (GB),Date
MAILSERVER01,600,2018-06-01
MAILSERVER01,600,2018-06-02
MAILSERVER01,610,2018-06-03
```

Comment: Are you trying create a merged CSV as output?

Comment: Ultimately yes. 

Something like:
`code`
VMName,Total Storage (GB),Date
MAILSERVER01,600,2018-06-01
MAILSERVER01,600,2018-06-02
MAILSERVER01,610,2018-06-03`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using the built in CSV library as follows:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import csv
import glob                        

req_fields = itemgetter(0, 8)       # Used to extract the two required fields from a list
header = ["VMName", "Total Storage (GB)", "Date"]

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    for filename in glob.glob(r'VM Resources*.csv'):
        date = filename.split()[3]  # split on spaces and take the 4th part

        with open(filename, newline='') as f_input:
            csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
            header = next(csv_input)    # skip the header

            for row in csv_input:
                output_row = list(req_fields(row)) + [date]
                csv_output.writerow(output_row)
```

Giving you an `output.csv` file that would look something like:

```
VMName,Total Storage (GB),Date
MAILSERVER01,600,2018-06-01
MAILSERVER01,600,2018-06-02
MAILSERVER01,610,2018-06-03
```

Tested on Python 3.6.7